# Automatically Remounting a USB Drive after USB errors

Tags: usb, disk-management

I have a Shuttle XS fanless computer with a double usb hard drive. It gets quite hot and the usb stack crashes in Ubuntu 11.04. This causes usb disks to eject, I'd like to make the computer remount usb drives after a certain amount of time.

How is this possible?

Comment: I assume you added the disc to /etc/fstab? If so what is the device name? And I would suggest fixing the problem and not problems that are causes by another problem (ie. fix the heating issue).

Comment: They are added to the fstab, but that made things worse by making the rediscovery of the drive not remount the drive, hence manual intervention.

Comment: OP are you still looking for an answer? If so, you may need to repost your question as this is flagged for closure. =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way I can think about is by making a script that unmounts USB drives.

A tip: you can unmount usb drives by doing:

```
sudo umount /dev/sdb1
```

`/dev/sdb1` should be replaced by your USB drive location.

Comment: How would unmounting the drives remount them?